# Working with hooks (SetWindowsHookEX & WH_GETMESSAGE)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, setwindowshookex

I'll start with a description of what exactly I need and why.

I am making an in-game interface in a library (dll), and I need the ability to both receive and delete messages (prevent the target process from receiving them), depending on different conditions in the code.

In addition to messages from the mouse and keyboard, I do not need anything else. For this, there are two ways. Find some kind of hook that will allow me to receive messages from both the mouse and the keyboard, or put two separate hooks on the mouse and keyboard, but there will be much more code than with one hook.

I decided to go the first way and put a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook on the messages of the thread that created the window. However, my attempts to block the message were unsuccessful.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK messageHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return -1; // This works fine with WH_MOUSE or WH_KEYBOARD, but for some reason, with the WH_GETMESSAGE hook, the process still receives a message
}
 
DWORD WINAPI messageDispatcher(LPVOID thread)
{
    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, messageHandler, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), *reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(thread));
 
    if (!hookHandle)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }
 
    MSG message{};
 
    while (GetMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if `WH_GETMESSAGE` is the right hook for me. Perhaps much more experienced programmers will tell me that it is better to do, for example, two hooks, `WH_MOUSE` and `WH_KEYBOARD`, rather than using `WH_GETMESSAGE`.

But if, nevertheless, using `WH_GETMESSAGE` is not a bad idea, then please help me to make it so that I can control the receipt of some messages by the process (do not allow them to be seen by the process).

Comment: Please help me. I have asked this question on another forum already two times and three times on stackoverflow.

Comment: "*I have asked this question on another forum already two times and three times on stackoverflow*" - if you are not getting the answers you need, that is probably a good indication that you are likely asking the wrong thing, or asking in the wrong way.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError mouse/keyboard activity goes though a thread's message queue. They will be forwarded to a window when dispatched from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I decided to go the first way and put the WH_GETMESSAGE hook on the messages of the thread that created the window. However, my attempts to block the message were unsuccessful.

Per the documentation, a `WH_GETESSAGE` hook cannot block a message, only view/modify it.  When the hook exits, the message is always delivered to the target thread:

[GetMsgProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85))

> The GetMsgProc hook procedure can examine or modify the message. After the hook procedure returns control to the system, the GetMessage or PeekMessage function returns the message, along with any modifications, to the application that originally called it.

`WH_MOUSE/_LL` and `WH_KEYBOARD/_LL` hooks, on the other hand, can block messages, per their respective documentations:

[MouseProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85))

[LowLevelMouseProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85))

[KeyboardProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85))

[LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85))

> If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.

As such...

> Perhaps much more experienced programmers will tell me that it is better to do, for example, two hooks, WH_MOUSE and WH_KEYBOARD, rather than using WH_GETMESSAGE.

You will indeed have to use separate `WH_MOUSE`/`WH_KEYBOARD` hooks.

Comment: Are you talking specifically about WH_GETMESSAGE or about all the hooks? Simply, with WH_MOUSE and WH_KEYBOARD it worked.

Comment: Only certain hooks can block messages. WH_GETMESSAGE is not one of them. WH_MOUSE and WH_KEYBOARD are. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. And what about return -1, is this the correct way or is it better somehow differently?

Comment: @AugustVishnevsky that is addressed in the documentation I quoted: "*return a **nonzero value***". That means the OS doesn't care what specific value you return, as long as it satisfies that requirement. `-1` is a non-zero value.