# Determine which window the message was sent (SetWindowsHookEx & WH_KEYBOARD)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, setwindowshookex

I need to be able to determine which window the message is intended for, but I don’t understand how to do it correctly. In `WH_MOUSE` has a special structure (`MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`) that stores the hwnd of the window, but where to get the hwnd in `WH_KEYBOARD`?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK messageHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // ???
}
 
DWORD WINAPI messageDispatcher(LPVOID thread)
{
    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, messageHandler, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), *reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(thread));
 
    if (!hookHandle)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }
 
    MSG message{};
 
    while (GetMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

In theory, I could use `GetForegroundWindow`, but it seems to me that this is a terrible option, because the window can receive a keyboard message from some other process (if another process sends a `SendMessage` to this window) and not the fact that the current window will be exactly the one for which the message was intended.

Comment: WH_KEYBOARD_LL is a global hook. With this, everything is correct for me, since I need messages from a specific thread that created the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time a keyboard action is generated, the OS doesn't know yet which window will eventually receive the message.  That is why the `WH_KEYBOARD` hook doesn't provide a target `HWND`, like a `WH_MOUSE` hook does (since a mouse message carries window-related coordinates).

When a keyboard message is being routed to a target, the message gets delivered to the window that currently has input focus.

Per [About Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input):

> The system posts keyboard messages to the message queue of the foreground thread that created the window with the keyboard focus. The keyboard focus is a temporary property of a window. The system shares the keyboard among all windows on the display by shifting the keyboard focus, at the user's direction, from one window to another. The window that has the keyboard focus receives (from the message queue of the thread that created it) all keyboard messages until the focus changes to a different window.

Since your hook runs inside of the message queue of the target thread, you can use [`GetFocus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getfocus) to get the target `HWND` at that time:

> Retrieves the handle to the window that has the keyboard focus, if the window is attached to the calling thread's message queue.

Otherwise, you can use a `WH_CALLWNDPROC/RET` hook instead, which gets called when the message is actually delivered to a window.  However, you can't block messages with this hook (as you were asking about in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205568/)).

Comment: As far as I know, WH_CALLWNDPROC does not register the keyboard at all (I already tried it once, then switched to WH_GETMESSAGE, which I asked in my previous question) Will try GetFocus, hope it helps. Thanks! <3

Comment: `WH_CALLWNDPROC` does not register the keyboard at all*" - It should. `WH_GETMESSAGE` is called for every posted message that is retrieved from a thread's message queue, before the message gets dispatched to a window. `WH_CALLWNDPROC` is called for every message that is delivered to a window, whether it is a sent message or a dispatched posted message.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is a hook of type `WH_JOURNALRECORD`.

With this, the callback procedure that Windows will call in response to the various events that this hook intercepts is of type [`JournalRecordProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644983(v=vs.85)), and the `lparam` parameter passed to this function points to an [`EVENTMSG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-eventmsg) structure, which looks like this:

```
typedef struct tagEVENTMSG {
  UINT  message;
  UINT  paramL;
  UINT  paramH;
  DWORD time;
  HWND  hwnd;
} EVENTMSG;
```

And there is your `hwnd`!

Comment: Journal hooks are meant for recording user input and then playing it back later.  That is not what is needed in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a global hook. I need messages from a specific thread that created the window.